# url parsing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, http, url, networking

I have been trying to experiment with a code for an http client that makes almost no use of urllib except for urllib.parse.  I want this program to act like `cURL` where you would be able to retrieve a url by a command such as:  `curl -g https://www.google.com` or `curl -v https://www.google.com`
I am however having some trouble with it although I am sure the code is correct.  Here is the code:

```
import socket
import argparse
from urllib.parse import urlparse

def httpc_get(url, verbose):

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    url = urlparse(url)
    s.connect((url.hostname, 80))
    request = "GET " + url.path + "?" + url.query + " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"
    s.sendall(request.encode("utf-8"))
    response = s.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
    if not verbose:
        response = response.split("\n")
        for i in range(9,len(response)):
            print(response[i])
    else:
        print(response)
    s.close
def httpc_post(url, header, data, verbose):
    # initialize the socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    url = urlparse(url)
    s.connect((url.hostname, 80))
    request = "POST " + url.path + " HTTP/1.0" + "\r\n" + "Host: "+ url.hostname + "\r\n" + header + "\r\n" + "Content-Length: " + str(len(data)) + "\r\n" + "\r\n" + data
    s.sendall(request.encode("utf-8"))
    response = s.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
    if not verbose:
        response = response.split("\n")
        for i in range(9,len(response)):
            print(response[i])
    else:
        print(response)
    s.close


# argument parsing
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
getVsPost = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
getVsPost.add_argument('-g', '--get', help='get with URL argument', type=str)
getVsPost.add_argument('-p', '--post', help='post with URL argument', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--header', help='header for HTTP post', type=str)
dataVsFile = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
dataVsFile.add_argument('-d', '--data', help='data string for HTTP post', type=str)
dataVsFile.add_argument('-f', '--file', help='file for HTTP post', type=str)
verbose = parser.add_argument('-v', '--verbose', help='show verbose output',
        action='store_true')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.get is not None:
    httpc_get(args.get, args.verbose)
elif args.post is not None and args.header is not None:
    if args.data is not None:
        httpc_post(args.post, args.header, args.data, args.verbose)
    elif args.file is not None:
        f = open(args.file, 'r')
        data = file.read()
        f.close()
        httpc_post(args.post, args.header, data, args.verbose)
    else:
        print("error: expected either a data string (-d) or file (-f) for post request.")
        parser.print_help()
elif args.post is not None and args.header is None:
    print("error: expected a header (--header) for post request.")
    parser.print_help()
else:
    parser.print_help()
```

whenever I run this code in the command line, let say for instance I run:

```
httpcl.py -g http://www.google.com
```

and no matter what other url I use, I get the following error:

```
httpcl.py: error: unrecognized arguments: http://www.google.com
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Odd, if I run `./httpcl.py -g http://www.google.com`, it doesn't show the error you mention, it seems to perform the get request correctly and shows the result.

Comment: @brm The results however are not similar to what `curl -g` produces.  Try for instance to run `curl -g http://httpbin.org`  and compare against `httpcl.py -g http://httpbin.org`

Comment: Print the request line you're sending, you'll find that it doesn't look quite right

Comment: @brm You are absolutely right.  The request does not look right.  However this is the part that is most disconcerting because `urlparse()` does not offer any other alternatives for printing the correct path except for `.path` which oddly prints only a partial path.  Any idea what other alternative is available?

Comment: A couple of remarks after playing around with it somewhat: you can easily check if `url.path` is empty, and use `/` if that's the case. About the empty response of  httpbin, that has to do with the fact that you're not sending any additional headers. Many websites are actually served by the same server program. To make this possible, the browser sends a `Host` header that informs the server of the website it's surfing to. Based on this, the server can then send the response that belongs to that website. So, if you also send e.g. `Host: httpbin.org`, you'll get a response.